# Прозрачный action bar

Tags: android, actionbar

Как сделать прозрачный Action Bar в андроид приложении? Что нужно добавить, чтобы пропала полоса под ним?

Код на стиля:

```
<style name="ProfileTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">   
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

[image: Результат на данный момент.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в разметку добавить `Toolbar` и назначить ему прозрачный background. На сколько я знаю, для `Toolbar` поумолчанию нет тени.

`Toolbar` с прозрачным фоном:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
```

Затем нужно убрать `ActionBar`. Изменяем тему приложения:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Дальше в методе `onCreate()` нашей активности (Должна быть наследником `AppCompatActivity` или `ActionBarActivity`) назначаем `Toolbar` как `ActionBar`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: На пятом андроиде есть тень, а на четвертом нету, так что от платформы зависит и от темы. Я еще не проверял, но думаю, что дело в параметре elevation, который надо просто поставить в 0.

Answer (score 0):

Я не проверял ваш код, но боюсь такая тема не прокатит со вставкой прозрачного фона в ActionBar, вы можете просто убрать его, а сверху добавить свой Layout и задать ему размеры и добавить туда элементы и функционал аналогичный ActionBar и задать прозрачный цвет и плов готов.

Comment: где вы увидели там прозрачный текст?

Comment: Ошибка, прозрачный фон

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в тему

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

также для Android 5+ необходимо добавить

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Ругается на `@null`.